# How to get rid of unwanted eggs

Tags: pokemon-go

I have a full component of eggs at the moment. Mostly 2k with a couple of 5k (and a 10k incubating )

Other than buying a load of incubators and walking loads. Is there a way to get rid of the more common eggs to give me a chance to pick up others.

There doesn't seem to be an equivalent to transfer for the eggs.

Comment: Don't know why that didn't show up when I searched. Thanks.

Comment: no problem. try using square brackets to limit the search onto a specific tag

Answer (score 0):

Currently there is no way to release or drop eggs in the game. (Version 0.29.2)

Just need to walk em off!